# Efficient query to split a delimited column into separate rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some data that includes a column with delimited data. There are multiple records in the same column essentially:

```
A0434168.A2367943.A18456972.A0135374.A0080362.A0084546.A0100991.A0064071.A0100858
```

I'm trying to split up the data in this column into separate rows in another table. The values are of variable length, and delimited by periods. I've been attempting to create a lookup table for this data, using a cursor. Due to the volume of data, the cursor is unreasonably slow.

My cursor looks like the following:

```
DECLARE @ptr nvarchar(160)
DECLARE @aui nvarchar(15)
DECLARE @getmrhier3 CURSOR 

SET @getmrhier3 = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  cast(ptr as nvarchar(160)),aui
    FROM    mrhier3
    FORWARD_ONLY
OPEN @getmrhier3
FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getmrhier3 INTO @ptr, @aui

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if(len(@ptr) > 0)
    begin
        if(charindex('.',@ptr) > 0)
        begin
            insert into mrhierlookup(hieraui,aui)
            values      (substring(@ptr,0,charindex('.',@ptr)),@aui)
            
            update  mrhier3
            set     ptr = substring(@ptr,charindex('.',@ptr)+1,LEN(@ptr))
            where   aui = @aui 
              and   ptr = @ptr
        end
        else
        begin
            insert into mrhierlookup(hieraui,aui)
            values      (@ptr,@aui)
            
            update  mrhier3
            set     ptr = ''
            where   aui = @aui 
              and   ptr = @ptr
        end
    end
    FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getmrhier3 INTO @ptr, @aui
END

CLOSE       @getmrhier3
DEALLOCATE  @getmrhier3
```

The current version of the cursor just works on the leading value of the column. All lengths are arbitrary. The column is at most ~150 characters long.

With the current dataset, building the lookup table will likely take days. It will have several million records.

Is there a better way to efficiently (quickly) parse out this data into a separate table for the purpose of performing join operations more quickly?

Comment: No offense, but how do you read your own code? Does it give you nightmares? Indents, carriage returns, white space and statement terminators go a LONG way.

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Comment: @xQbert: similar, but still different because of column orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings(@List NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM
       ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
         FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'
         + REPLACE(@List, '.', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
           ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
       WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

Then get rid of all the cursor and looping nonsense and do this:

```
INSERT dbo.mrhierlookup
(
  heiraui,
  aui
)
SELECT s.Item, m.aui
  FROM dbo.mrhier3 AS m
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(m.ptr) AS s
GROUP BY s.Item, m.aui;
```

Comment: That worked, and created a table with a few million rows in about 5 seconds!