# Split string in single column (& multiple rows) into multiple columns in SQL Server (missing data exists)

Tags: sql-server, substring, cross-apply, charindex

Following is how my data looks like:

In one column & several rows:

```
[column]
variable1:A,variable2:B,variable3:C,variable4:D,...,variable9:I
variable1:A,variable2:B,variable4:D,.....variable7:G
variable8:H,variable9:I
variable9:I
.
.
.
.
```

and I am trying to split as such:

```
variable1 | variabel2 | variable3| variable4| ...variable7| variable8|varaible9
A           B              C            D           G         H           I
A           B                           D     
                                                              H           I
                                                                          I
```

I am working on this code:

```
--Approach 1. cross apply

select Finaldata.*

from [dbo].[table_name]
cross apply ( select str = [dbo].[table_name].attributes + ',,' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ',', str ) ) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ',', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
cross apply ( select p3 = charindex( ',', str, p2 + 1 ) ) ap3
cross apply ( select p4 = charindex( ',', str, p3 + 1 ) ) ap4
cross apply ( select p5 = charindex( ',', str, p4 + 1 ) ) ap5
cross apply ( select p6 = charindex( ',', str, p5 + 1 ) ) ap6
cross apply ( select p7 = charindex( ',', str, p6 + 1 ) ) ap7
cross apply ( select p8 = charindex( ',', str, p7 + 1 ) ) ap8
cross apply ( select p9 = charindex( ',', str, p8 + 1 ) ) ap9

cross apply ( select variable1 = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )                   
             ,variable2 = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 )
             ,variable3 = substring( str, p2+1, p3-p2-1 )
             ,variable4 = substring( str, p3+1, p4-p3-1 )
             ,variable5 = substring( str, p4+1, p5-p4-1 )
             ,variable6 = substring( str, p5+1, p6-p5-1 )
             ,variable7 = substring( str, p6+1, p7-p6-1 )
             ,variable8 = substring( str, p7+1, p8-p7-1 )
             ,variable9 = substring( str, p8+1, p9-p8-1 )
      )Finaldata


--Approach 2. substring & charindex
--strings are in column 'attributes'

substring(attributes, charindex(attributes, 'variable1'),charindex(attributes, ',')-1) variable1
substring(attributes, charindex(attributes, 'variable2'),charindex(attributes, ',')-1) variable2
substring(attributes, charindex(attributes, 'variable3'),charindex(attributes, ',')-1) variable3
substring(attributes, charindex(attributes, 'variable4'),charindex(attributes, ',')-1) variable4
substring(attributes, charindex(attributes, 'variable5'), charindex(attributes, ',')-1) variable5
```

which I get same error message:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

I tried other codes using syntax substring & charindex, parsename etc that are already on internet, but they are not working. I assume it is because I am trying to split string into many columns & there are missing data to be considered.

Please help me!!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses a `SplitString` function to split the input strings. This function was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10182629/243373) on the question [Efficient query to split a delimited column into a separate table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10182533/243373). Slightly modified for different separator (`.` → `,`).

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,col VARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO #tt(col)VALUES
('variable1:A,variable2:B,variable3:C,variable4:D,variable9:I'),
('variable1:A,variable2:B,variable4:D,variable7:G'),
('variable8:H,variable9:I'),
('variable9:I');

SELECT
    variable1=ISNULL(variable1,''),
    variable2=ISNULL(variable2,''),
    variable3=ISNULL(variable3,''),
    variable4=ISNULL(variable4,''),
    variable5=ISNULL(variable5,''),
    variable6=ISNULL(variable6,''),
    variable7=ISNULL(variable7,''),
    variable8=ISNULL(variable8,''),
    variable9=ISNULL(variable9,'')
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            id,
            v_col=LEFT(item,CHARINDEX(':',item)-1),
            v_val=SUBSTRING(item,CHARINDEX(':',item)+1,LEN(item))
        FROM 
            #tt 
            CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(col)
    ) AS s
    PIVOT (
        MAX(v_val) FOR
        v_col IN (variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5,variable6,variable7,variable8,variable9)
    ) AS p

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| variable1 | variable2 | variable3 | variable4 | variable5 | variable6 | variable7 | variable8 | variable9 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| A         | B         | C         | D         |           |           |           |           | I         |
| A         | B         |           | D         |           |           | G         |           |           |
|           |           |           |           |           |           |           | H         | I         |
|           |           |           |           |           |           |           |           | I         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016 you can use this approach and built-in STRING_SPLIT function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

Comment: @JocaPC Oooh waaw... they've finally gone that far eh =). Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @TT. thanks for the answer! I am working on this now

Comment: and @JocaPC Thanks you so much!! I was trying to come up with splitstrings function from TT's codes. I'll try with built-in STRING_SPLIT function

Comment: @wannabhappy The script I posted should work just fine. That `STRING_SPLIT` function is new in SQL Server 2016. 2016 is still in beta phase so I doubt you can use this in production.

Comment: @wannabhappy In the link referring to the `StringSplit` function, replace `REPLACE(@List, '.', '</i><i>')` with `REPLACE(@List, ',', '</i><i>')`

Comment: @TT.BTW, last question ;( I also have been trying to add/change the code above so that the results(each rows) match with the id data that already exists in the same table but different column of the strings. Is this code the right approach, or is this sth I have to come up very new? I was hoping I can add on the given code..ie `CREATE TABLE [Shop].[dbo].[ttt](SELECT shop_id FROM [Shop].[dbo].[products] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,col VARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO [Shop].[dbo].[ttt](col) SELECT attributes FROM [Shop].[dbo].[products];`

Comment: @TT.thanks for the help again! If this is totally new lines of codes that I have to come up, just ignore my question as it will be the off the original topic-- THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @wannabhappy You're welcome of course. It's a bit hard to understand what your new question is...